# Bash script optimization for waiting for a particular string in log files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using a bash script that calls multiple processes which have to start up in a particular order, and certain actions have to be completed (they then print out certain messages to the logs) before the next one can be started. The bash script has the following code which works really well for most cases:

```
tail -Fn +1 "$log_file" | while read line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -qEi "$search_text"; then
        echo "[INFO] $process_name process started up successfully"
        pkill -9 -P $$ tail
        return 0
    elif echo "$line" | grep -qEi '^error\b'; then
        echo "[INFO] ERROR or Exception is thrown listed below. $process_name process startup aborted"
        echo "  ($line)  "
        echo "[INFO] Please check $process_name process log file=$log_file for problems"
        pkill -9 -P $$ tail
        return 1
    fi
done
```

However, when we set the processes to print logging in DEBUG mode, they print so much logging that this script cannot keep up, and it takes about 15 minutes after the process is complete for the bash script to catch up. Is there a way of optimizing this, like changing 'while read line' to 'while read 100 lines', or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about not forking up to two `grep` processes per log line?

```
tail -Fn +1 "$log_file" | grep -Ei "$search_text|^error\b" | while read line; do
```

So one long running `grep` process shall do preprocessing if you will.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, it is safer to add `--line-buffered` to the `grep` invocation.

Comment: It was working sometimes, but not others (it was hanging) - some research on SO shows that I also need to add the line buffer (grep --line-buffered -qEi "$search_text|^error\b") to guarantee that the output from grep is sent to read line as soon as it is found, instead of being lost in grep's internal buffer

Comment: Oops wait, I think I actually made a boo-boo there. It should be just `grep -Ei`, because `grep -qEi` will **drop** the lines that actual match. Argh! (How this ever worked for you is currently somewhat beyond me;)

Comment: Ah yes my bad - I did actually notice that and took the 'q' out and forgot to comment back :) But if you don't put in the line-buffered, it will not work if the line you are looking for is the last line in the file, unless by complete chance that line is the one that fills up the grep page buffer

Answer (score 0):

Some tips relevant for this script:

- [Checking that the service is doing its job](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#Starting_a_.22daemon.22_and_checking_whether_it_started_successfully) is a much better check for daemon startup than looking at the log output
- You can use `grep ... <<<"$line"` to execute fewer `echo`s.
- You can use `tail -f | grep -q ...` to avoid the `while` loop by stopping as soon as there's a matching line.
- If you can avoid `-i` on `grep` it might be significantly faster to process the input.
- [Thou shalt not `kill -9`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...)